# codeigniter website opens live website when links on local is clicked

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I am doing a project in codeigniter, am completely new to the framework. I am trying to edit the website on local machine, but whenever i am trying to access some page on local machine, its taking me to the live website.

Below is my index.php in root

```
<?php

switch (ENVIRONMENT)
{
    case 'development':
        error_reporting(-1);
        ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    break;

    case 'testing':
    case 'production':
        ini_set('display_errors', 0);
        if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.3', '>='))
        {
            error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT & ~E_USER_NOTICE & ~E_USER_DEPRECATED);
        }
        else
        {
            error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_STRICT & ~E_USER_NOTICE);
        }
    break;

    default:
        header('HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable.', TRUE, 503);
        echo 'The application environment is not set correctly.';
        exit(1); // EXIT_ERROR
}

/*
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 * SYSTEM DIRECTORY NAME
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 *
 * This variable must contain the name of your "system" directory.
 * Set the path if it is not in the same directory as this file.
 */
    $system_path = 'system';

/*
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 * APPLICATION DIRECTORY NAME
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 *
 * If you want this front controller to use a different "application"
 * directory than the default one you can set its name here. The directory
 * can also be renamed or relocated anywhere on your server. If you do,
 * use an absolute (full) server path.
 * For more info please see the user guide:
 *
 * https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/managing_apps.html
 *
 * NO TRAILING SLASH!
 */
    $application_folder = 'application';

/*
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 * VIEW DIRECTORY NAME
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 *
 * If you want to move the view directory out of the application
 * directory, set the path to it here. The directory can be renamed
 * and relocated anywhere on your server. If blank, it will default
 * to the standard location inside your application directory.
 * If you do move this, use an absolute (full) server path.
 *
 * NO TRAILING SLASH!
 */
    $view_folder = '';




/*
 * -------------------------------------------------------------------
 *  CUSTOM CONFIG VALUES
 * -------------------------------------------------------------------
 *
 * The $assign_to_config array below will be passed dynamically to the
 * config class when initialized. This allows you to set custom config
 * items or override any default config values found in the config.php file.
 * This can be handy as it permits you to share one application between
 * multiple front controller files, with each file containing different
 * config values.
 *
 * Un-comment the $assign_to_config array below to use this feature
 */
    // $assign_to_config['name_of_config_item'] = 'value of config item';




    // Set the current directory correctly for CLI requests
    if (defined('STDIN'))
    {
        chdir(dirname(__FILE__));
    }

    if (($_temp = realpath($system_path)) !== FALSE)
    {
        $system_path = $_temp.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
    }
    else
    {
        // Ensure there's a trailing slash
        $system_path = strtr(
            rtrim($system_path, '/\\'),
            '/\\',
            DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR
        ).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
    }

    // Is the system path correct?
    if ( ! is_dir($system_path))
    {
        header('HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable.', TRUE, 503);
        echo 'Your system folder path does not appear to be set correctly. Please open the following file and correct this: '.pathinfo(__FILE__, PATHINFO_BASENAME);
        exit(3); // EXIT_CONFIG
    }

    // The name of THIS file
    define('SELF', pathinfo(__FILE__, PATHINFO_BASENAME));

    // Path to the system directory
    define('BASEPATH', $system_path);

    // Path to the front controller (this file) directory
    define('FCPATH', dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);

    // Name of the "system" directory
    define('SYSDIR', basename(BASEPATH));

    // The path to the "application" directory
    if (is_dir($application_folder))
    {
        if (($_temp = realpath($application_folder)) !== FALSE)
        {
            $application_folder = $_temp;
        }
        else
        {
            $application_folder = strtr(
                rtrim($application_folder, '/\\'),
                '/\\',
                DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR
            );
        }
    }
    elseif (is_dir(BASEPATH.$application_folder.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR))
    {
        $application_folder = BASEPATH.strtr(
            trim($application_folder, '/\\'),
            '/\\',
            DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR
        );
    }
    else
    {
        header('HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable.', TRUE, 503);
        echo 'Your application folder path does not appear to be set correctly. Please open the following file and correct this: '.SELF;
        exit(3); // EXIT_CONFIG
    }

    define('APPPATH', $application_folder.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);

    // The path to the "views" directory
    if ( ! isset($view_folder[0]) && is_dir(APPPATH.'views'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR))
    {
        $view_folder = APPPATH.'views';
    }
    elseif (is_dir($view_folder))
    {
        if (($_temp = realpath($view_folder)) !== FALSE)
        {
            $view_folder = $_temp;
        }
        else
        {
            $view_folder = strtr(
                rtrim($view_folder, '/\\'),
                '/\\',
                DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR
            );
        }
    }
    elseif (is_dir(APPPATH.$view_folder.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR))
    {
        $view_folder = APPPATH.strtr(
            trim($view_folder, '/\\'),
            '/\\',
            DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR
        );
    }
    else
    {
        header('HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable.', TRUE, 503);
        echo 'Your view folder path does not appear to be set correctly. Please open the following file and correct this: '.SELF;
        exit(3); // EXIT_CONFIG
    }

    define('VIEWPATH', $view_folder.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);

require_once BASEPATH.'core/CodeIgniter.php';
```

I need to stop the pages taking me to live website. I need to access it local. I need to edit my pages in localhost and I want to access the pages on local machine only. Can anyone help me?

Comment: please check which value set in your  $config['base_url']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you are using your production servers configuration file while developing locally. Specifically, your `base_url` is not set properly. You can make two separate folders `production` and `development` in the `config` folder that has your database and configuration files for the respective environment in them.

https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/config.html#environments

Example:

[image]

[image]

So you only need to have different `index.php` files, one with development (on localhost) and one with production (live version).

Comment: i changed the base url, i could access the main page but its not showing any styles and other pages are like "object not found" how do i fix it

Comment: comments aren't for additional questions outside of the one above: https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment. in your case you probably don't have your style url/image urls correctly set; maybe they are hardcoded or the path doesn't resolve on local, idk, im not a mind reader.